# how can i remove a index page from other pages in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a template html page(say Index page) containing a header and three other pages and i want that Header on first two pages but not on third page .Using angularjs routing I am able to have that header on all three pages but cant hide that header from the third page.The pages have different controllers as well .Can anybody help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Which routing you are using? ngRoute or ui-router?

Comment: ng-Roue and I solve it using $rootscope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **This is not a good practice, not at all! But as your question lacks of code...**

You say "The pages have different controllers", so let's say you have `PageOneCtrl`, `PageTwoCtrl` and `PageThreeCtrl`.

If you want to show the header on the page with controllers, let's say: `PageOneCtrl` and `PageTwoCtrl`, set a `$scope` (remember you have to define `$scope` on that controller first) variable just like:

`$scope.showHeader = true;`

And in `PageThreeCtrl` (where you want to HIDE the header element) write

`$scope.showHeader = false;`

Then in the html you should write:

`<header ng-if="showHeader">This is your header content</header>`

the `ng-if` will do the trick, check angularjs documentation for more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Doesn't work? Try `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`, but watch out! If you use `$rootScope` then you should declare that variable on **every controller**.

> **This is not a good practice, not at all! But as your question lacks of code...**

A better practice, and one of the bests in my opinion, would be to use angular-ui-router and set a `data` attribute to the state (route) with something like

```
.state('myRoute', {
    templateUrl: 'views/my-route-view.html',
    controller: 'MyrouteCtrl',
    data: {
        hideHeader: true;
    }
})
```

, in a `.run()` function set something like `$rootScope.$state = $state` (read more about it in the [ui.router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)) and then simply: `<header ng-if="!$state.current.data.hideHeader">`. But I believe you're not an advanced developer to do it :) So keep learning.